# Image defer script instead of lazy image script leads to undefined offset?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, opencart

In order to improve the pagespeed of my website, Pagespeed Insight suggest to use deferred images instead of lazy jQuery images. I did an attempt according to the recommendations from another topic

[Reference Topic on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396068/speed-up-page-load-by-deferring-images)

I use opencart 2 and I tried to change the code in the following way:

1. I created a small 1x1 pixel gif picture and uploaded this as image/imgdefer.gif.
2. I placed a javascript file in the head of my header.tpl template which is used for all pages. The script is completely conform to the instructions I found on stackoverflow (sse link above) and [varvy.com](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/defer-images.html). The javascript used is:

   ```
   <script>
   function init() {
   var imgDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
   for (var i=0; i<imgDefer.length; i++) {
   if(imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
      imgDefer[i].setAttribute('src',imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
   } } }
   window.onload = init;
   </script>
   ```
3. I replaced the lazy images code in the main.tpl template by the script proposed script in the article, so

Existing Lazy Image script:

```
<a href="<?php echo $submenu_item['href']; ?>">
   <img width="<?php echo $submenu_item['image_width']; ?>" height="<?php  echo $submenu_item['image_height']; ?>" class="lazy" src="<?php echo $submenu_item['dummy']; ?>" data-src="<?php echo $submenu_item['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $submenu_item['name']; ?>"/>
</a>
```

was replaced by

```
<a href="<?php echo $submenu_item['href']; ?>">
   <img width="<?php echo $submenu_item['image_width']; ?>" height="<?php echo $submenu_item['image_height']; ?>" src="image/imgdefer.gif" data-src="<?php echo $submenu_item['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $submenu_item['name']; ?>"/>
</a>
```

4. After applying the code changes in points 1 to 3 above, I receive a notice about a missing offset in  vq2_system_modification_system_library_response.php in line 115. The concerned piece of code is listed below. It is the first if instruction (if (count($info) == 3 && $info[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396068/speed-up-page-load-by-deferring-images)[0] == 'src') {) which generates the error.

   ```
   preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i', $this->output, $result);

   $img = array();
   foreach($result[0] as $img_tag) {
       preg_match_all('/(width|height|src)=("[^"]*")/i',$img_tag, $img[$img_tag]);
   }
   foreach ($img as $k => $info) {
       if (count($info) == 3 && $info[1][0] == 'src') {
       //if (curl_init(str_replace('"', '', $info[2][0]))) {
          $imgfile = str_replace('"', '', $info[2][0]);
          $imgfile = str_replace(HTTP_SERVER, DIR_IMAGE . '../', $imgfile);
          $imgfile = str_replace(HTTPS_SERVER, DIR_IMAGE . '../', $imgfile);
          if (file_exists($imgfile)) {
              $image_info = getImageSize(str_replace('"', '', $imgfile));
              $k = trim($k, '/>');
              $k = trim($k, '>');
              $this->output = str_replace($k, ($k . ' ' . $image_info[3]), $this->output);
          }
       }
   }
   ```
5. I did some simulations and I have the impression that `$info[1][0]` sometimes give 0 as value (empty array?).

Are there suggestions that could help me out and point me in the correct direction? Is this the correct way to implement deferred images?

UPDATE:

I applied the proposal of Novice below which seemed very logical, but the same error "Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in vqmod\vqcache\vq2-system_modification_system_library_response.php on line 115" persists. Only when I delete the script file from point 2 out of my header.tpl, the error is gone.

Could it be that my deferred images only will start loading later (too late) and that the code in point 4 can not be properly executed at the moment it is requested? The code in point 4 is used to provide image and height attributes for all images on the page according to recommendations from google pagespeed?

How to solve? I'm breaking my head for a few days already on this problem, so any suggestions would be very appreciated.

I have to add that there are also other `<img>` tags - not lazy loading - on this page, but I have deleted all these tags one by one and no matter which img tag I delete, the notice warning persists...

Regards,

SabKo

Answer (score 0):

It's not empty actually it's failing due to the fact that`$info[1][0]` is equal to `"width"` it's so because the regexp. scans in sequential manner whatever comes first get put first since you put `width` attribute first it goes to gets first position(`[0]`).Note that sequence of qualifies inside an regexp. doesn't matter ie. in most of the cases `'/(width|height|src)=("[^"]*")/i` gives exactly same output as `'/(src|height|width)=("[^"]*")/i`.What really matter is order of attributes in your tags **what comes first in your subject string and passes the test will get put first**.

So if you change tag related code like this

```
<img src="image/imgdefer.gif" width="<?php echo $submenu_item['image_width']; ?>" height="<?php echo $submenu_item['image_height']; ?>"  data-src="<?php echo $submenu_item['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $submenu_item['name']; ?>"/>
```

Then it would work fine I guess.In case you don't want to change that order you can also edit the condition like `if (count($info) == 3 && $info[1][2] == 'src')`