# Image deferring is not considered anymore by GTmetrix

Tags: javascript, image, deferred-loading, gtmetrix

I have used this image deferring technique, as described here:

[Speed up page load by deferring images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396068/speed-up-page-load-by-deferring-images)

As mentioned, I have used this code and everything was OK on GTmetrix rates.
Recently I have tested my site on GTmetrix and suddenly GTmetrix is not considering the images as being deferred. First I had approx. 30 server request (images were considered deferred), and now, the same site scores approx. 170 !!! server requests.

Please find the documents here, before and after:

SITE: www.webstrategy.ro

1. GTmetrix document is considering the fact that the assets are deferred and a small number of server requests:
   http://www.webstrategy.ro/docs/GTmetrix-report-webstrategy.ro-20161230T071513-JvEGYTS5-full.pdf
2. Now GTmetrix shows an extremely high number of server request, although the assets are deferred
   http://www.webstrategy.ro/docs/GTmetrix-report-www.webstrategy.ro-20170209T082653-cTeOlFkH-full.pdf

Please compare the two documents. I haven't changed anything at the website code meanwhile. Is the same. Why is different now? Why GTmetrix doesn't consider anymore the fact that the assets are deferred?

Anybody had the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sent this question also to GTmetrix and got the answer.
The difference between the two reports has appeared because, as with February 8, 2017 GTmetrix has changed the moment when it considers a web page is fully loaded.

More details here:

https://gtmetrix.com/faq.html#faq-fully-loaded-vs-onload

https://gtmetrix.com/faq.html#faq-fully-loaded-longer-why

Best regards!